# What would be next after minor, major, ....?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that would describe a third category following a "minor" and "major" category. (For compatibility reasons it won't do to insert a middle category of "moderate" or the like.) Example usage:

> After fighting past several minor encounters, and a few major
>   encounters, the adventurers finally made contact with the _____ encounter.

Comment: How about [_climactic_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/climactic)?

Comment: "most excellent"

Comment: One doesn't really "make contact" with an "encounter". Nonetheless I'd suggest "... the adventurers were faced with _their greatest enemy_" or "... _the ultimate test of will_" ("supreme" is really more reserved for gods or fascist leaders :D)

Comment: How is this unclear? He is looking for the mother of all encounters, which would be against a totally OP opp, obviously.

Comment: I don't believe this is unclear. There is a description and an example sentence. Translating the Latin into English, *minor, major _______* would be *less, more,* and something like *most.* The answers supply that.

Comment: @Drew I don't get it. I mean, I like porridge and in fact I play badminton but still... Care to elaborate?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: It wasn't serious. (I've deleted the comment.)

Comment: I would suggest *penultimate*, since it leaves you room for one more after that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's implied that there are no further obstacles - ***final***.

If it's implied that there's no greater obstacle - ***supreme***.

If it's implied that there's no passing the obstacle - ***overwhelming***.

If it's required to keep some kind of hierarchy - ***capital***.

Comment: "Capital" is indeed what I'm tentatively using at the moment.

Answer (score 22):

The word ***supreme*** is a good suggestion. You could also consider using [***ultimate***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ultimate):

> ***greatest*** or ***most extreme***

[***Final***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/final) could be a candidate, too:

> coming at the end :  being the last in a series, process, or progress

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: *Ultimate* might be a good choice.

Comment: Although in context, "finally made contact with the ultimate encounter" has an unfortunate air of tautology about it. It's not wrong but it's not quite elegant.

Answer (score 8):

Minor and major are Latin comparatives for small and large respectively, so what is wanted is a superlative. I suggest *[supreme](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supreme).*

A musician, however, might suggest Dorian, Lydian, Phrygian, Mixo-Lydian, or Locrian.

Answer (score 4):

**Climactic** or, as others have suggested, **ultimate** might work when referring to something that happens at or near the end of a sequence of events.

If you are looking for something in the middle or towards the beginning, **prime** is a good choice.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a nerdy audience, which it sounds like you might, you could use **boss**, as in video games and tabletop RPGs.

If that's not the case, you might use **final**, although you would have to recast your sentence to avoid the repetition.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, ***critical***

> Having a decisive or crucial importance in the success, failure, or existence of something [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/critical)
>
> *After fighting past several minor encounters, and a few major encounters, the adventurers finally made contact with the **critical** encounter.*

Comment: +1 for "critical" (*I am surprised that you got 3 downvotes*). Depending on the context, "vital" or "inescapable" may fit.

Comment: @Graffito critical is a much better option than the post originally suggested.  :-)

Comment: This is the only option that I feel describes a category of battle like OP asked. Most of the other suggestions refer to a single battle, but not a type of battle.

Comment: @Neptunian singularity is implied by *the*, rather than *a* encounter?

Answer (score 2):

If it's the most important encounter in the series, and specifically the encounter that "matters" from a plot perspective, you might call it the [*primary*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/primary) encounter:

> 2
>   a :  of first rank, importance, or value :  principal
>   (Merriam-Webster)

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with an adjective borrowed from Latin, in which language *maior* (= 'major') is a comparative from the root *magnus*, the English adjective formed from the borrowed superlative of the same root is

> **maximal**, *adj.*
>   1. Of or constituting a maximum; of the greatest possible size, duration, or capacity.

["maximal, adj.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/115258 (accessed December 20, 2015).]

In your example sentence, this might be phrased as

> After fighting through several minor encounters, and a few major encounters, the adventurers finally fought through the maximal encounter.

Because 'minor' and 'major' are adjectives in English (regardless of being borrowed from comparatives in Middle French and Latin, respectively), the superlative adjectival phrase

> **most major**

is another possibility. This would be a rare use, but not unprecedented. Hence,

> Their fighting ranged from the most minor to the most major encounters.